# Angular.js How can i set a constant in the login controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple login controller thats handles the app login process. on the module level, i have created a constant like this:

```
.constant('MyConstant', [{
    id: null,
    user: null
}])
```

In my Login controller i pass in the constant like so:

```
.controller('loginController', [
    '$scope',
    'MyConstant',
    function ($scope, MyConstant) {
        //here i want to change the constants data like this:
        MyConstant.user = 'My new username'
    }
])
```

But when i call the constant here i get undefined?
How is the proper way to handle this? Or is it better to do this entirely different?

And then when calling other controlers i want to be able to use this new data:

```
 .controller('otherController', [
         '$scope',
         'MyConstant',
        function ($scope, MyConstant) {
            //this should return 'My new username'
            console.log(MyConstant.user);
        }
    ])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
.constant('MyConstant', [{
    id: null,
    user: null
}])
```

to

```
.constant('MyConstant', {
    id: null,
    user: null
})
```

and add constant `service` in controller:

```
.controller('otherController', [
    '$scope', 'MyConstant',
    function ($scope, MyConstant) {
        //this should return 'My new username'
        console.log(MyConstant.user);
    }
])
```

And used as **shared service**(define in **root**) so that can use in any controller(whole application)

should work.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to inject `MyConstant` in `otherController`.

But that should not resolve your issue.
A constant is useful for API endpoints, or any value that you don't have to change inside of your app.

Why would you not use a service/factory ?

See http://bguiz.github.io/js-standards/angularjs/constants/